# Letsencrypt SSL certificate error

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, lets-encrypt

So I deleted the certificate thinking that I needed to do that since I got a new domain name. I am currently stuck with the current error:

```
Root@Site:~$ certbot-auto --apache -d example.io -d www.example.io
Requesting root privileges to run certbot...
/home/maiale/.local/share/letsencrypt/bin/letsencrypt --apache -d example.io -d www.maiale.io
Saving debug log to /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log
Error while running apache2ctl configtest.
Action 'configtest' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.

AH00526: Syntax error on line 35 of /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default-le-ssl.conf:
SSLCertificateFile: file '/etc/letsencrypt/live/maialedesigns.com/cert.pem' does not exist or is empty

The apache plugin is not working; there may be problems with your existing configuration.
The error was: MisconfigurationError("Error while running apache2ctl configtest.\nAction 'configtest' failed.\nThe Apache error log may have more information.\n\nAH00526: Syntax error on line 35 of /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default-le-ssl.conf:\nSSLCertificateFile: file '/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/cert.pem' does not exist or is empty\n",)
```

This is what I get when I try to run `./certbot-auto` or `./certbot-auto --apache`.
Is there any way to fix this issue?

If you need any more information let me know.

Edit: This is running Ubuntu 14.04.4

Comment: You need to add your domain to your Apache virtual host first, Did you try with a domain which is registered in you Apache virtual host and site-enabled?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Answer (score 2):

Before getting `SSL` for you domain, you need to register your domain in your Apache virtual host, the domain can either be a real domain which you set the `DNS` to your server IP, or it can be a fake domain defined in your Ubuntu `hosts` file.

In both ways you need to add your domain to Apache virtual host and then enable it to store a symbolic link from `sites-available` into `sites-enabled` folder of your Apache.

To do that, first you need to `cd` into the `sites-available` Apache directory using the following command `cd /etc/apache2/sites-available/`, then if you `ll` from the directory there is a file called `000-default.conf` which is the default setting and configuration of Apache, make a copy from it in that directory (it is good practice to name it the same as your domain name), `sudo cp 000-default.conf example.com.conf`, (`sudo` is required because of permission).
After the file is copied open the file using `nano`, `vim` or whatever terminal editor you are comfortable with. `sudo nano example.com.conf`.

When the file is opened configure your domain as the following (set these lines with the proper configuration):

```
ServerName www.example.com [You domain name]
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost [Email of webmaster]
DocumentRoot /var/www/html [The root of you website's files which the domain will open]
```

After you did the configuration, save the file and exit. Then use the following command to enable your website and it will make the symbolic link into your `sites-enabled` directory: `sudo a2ensite example.com.conf`.

Then you only need to restart you Apache `sudo systemctl restart apache2.service`. Then you have your domain available and accessible through url and you also can get SSL certificate from `letsencrypt`.

P.S: You can read more about Apache virtual hosts from these two URLs: [Apache Documents](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/name-based.html) and [Digitalocean Tutorials](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts)

P.S: If you have your previous domain and SSL removed, make sure it has been removed completely from your Apache configuration and virtual host that includes `sites-available`, `sites-enabled`, and all the files related to your previous domain.